# Windows service hardening: Write-Restricted tokens & smb

Tags: windows, security, service, smb, sid

I have a service that runs as `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` that periodically reads a file from a smb share. This works just fine in unrestricted mode (`sc.exe sidtype MyService unrestricted` and `sc.exe sidtype MyService none`).

Now I would like to make my service write restricted in order to further limit potential security repercussions. If I understand service hardening correctly I can do so by executing `sc.exe sidtype MyService restricted` and then my service should continue to be able to read anything it was capable of reading when running in unrestricted mode, but writing should be limited to ACLs granting explicit permissions to `NT SERVICE\MyService`. However after doing so, the service can no longer read from the remote share. Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to make this possible?

I'm having trouble understanding windows service hardening. I come from the UNIX world and I really can't find any good detailed documents explaining service privileges etc. So if you can recommend a book or a site in the comments I would appreciate that. So far the best summary I was able to find is this blog article: https://www.itprotoday.com/security/understanding-windows-service-hardening.

I've already asked this question on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/981242/323496), because I didn't receive any answers there, even with a bounty, I've asked to close it there and I'm reasking it here. There Harry Johnston commented, that his best guess would be that SMB doesn't support restricted tokens, which sounds plausible to me, but we both couldn't find any confirmation on that by searching the internet.

Comment: From what I understand, calling "sc restricted" will add the service's SID to the token's list of restricted sids. Undercovers, I guess sc.exe calls ChangeServiceConfig2  with a SERVICE_SID_INFO structured set to SERVICE_SID_TYPE_RESTRICTED. This is different then calling CreateRestrictedToken with a WRITE_RESTRICTED flag. So, to me, it's not a Write-restricted token, just a restricted token (which is somewhat stronger than a Write-restricted token because it does not only considers write accesses but all accesses...) Have you indeed added an ACL with the service's SID?

Comment: I have explicitilly added the service SID to the ACL but I doubt that the restricted SID in general has access to the SMB share. I'm pretty sure you're right with your assumbution and now that I have read the docs for CreateRestrictedToken it all makes more sense to me. Also with CreateRestrictedToken as keyword I've found this great article: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/secure-programming-cookbook/0596003943/ch01s02.html. I think AdjustTokenPrivileges is what I want to add to the startup of my service. If you make your comment an anwser I'm gonna accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that only CreateRestrictedToken allows for write only access and there is no way to restrict access on an allready existing process. Since relaunching the process isn't really an option for me. I'm just gonna leave the service running in unrestricted mode.

Comment: I don't see why a restricted SID tokens would no support SMB. They're just added to the restricted token (you can get it with sc showsid). I can't test it because for this to work the two machines must be in an AD domain (I don't have one). Anyway, if you want to restrict the rights the service has, you can just create a custom account for this and define proper rights on server side. NetworkService is more a facility when you don't want to manage a list of custom accounts (password expiration, etc.), more an "all or nothing" feature, and kind of contradicts your higher security requirements.

Comment: You can also use the connecting machine account (NetworkService uses this when talking to another machine in the domain) to restrict rights.

Comment: you set [`SERVICE_SID_TYPE_RESTRICTED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_sid_info) - now your service run with [restricted token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/restricted-tokens) - *When a restricted process or thread tries to access a securable object, the system performs two access checks: one using the token's enabled SIDs, and another using the list of restricting SIDs. Access is granted only if both access checks allow the requested access rights.*.

Comment: and in *the restricted SID list:* - *World SID S-1-1-0
Service logon SID
Write-restricted SID S-1-5-33* - so by fact your process run as everyone access. if you special not add read access only for *S-1-5-33*

Comment: so i be say you wrong understand what effect make your token is [*Restricted*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/restricted-tokens) - this really very restrict your process - *the service can no longer read from the remote share.* - it can read only if *Everyone* (*S-1-1-0*) also can read. so yes - this is expected behavior.

Comment: solution - you need add [*S-1-5-33*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab) sid to your share and allow read access for this sid

Comment: i for example run *Print Spooler* service now as restricted, unrestricted and none -
 and dump it token groups - https://pastebin.com/LrbbB0T7

Comment: so if you want read only access for share - you need special add access alowed ACE to DACL which enable read only access to [S-1-5-33] 'NT AUTHORITY\WRITE RESTRICTED' sid or to concrete your service sid. in case spooler this is [S-1-5-80-3951239711-1671533544-1416304335-3763227691-3930497994] 'NT SERVICE\Spooler' - your service of course will be have another

Comment: [`Service SIDs`](https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/understanding-service-sids.html) - this is *S-1-5-80-{SHA1 hash of short service name}*

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/voy/2007/04/01/write-restricted-token/

Answer (score 2):

```
sc.exe sidtype MyService restricted
```

use [`ChangeServiceConfig2W`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-changeserviceconfig2w) call with [`SERVICE_CONFIG_SERVICE_SID_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_sid_info). and set `dwServiceSidType` to `SERVICE_SID_TYPE_RESTRICTED`. as result your server will be run with [*Restricted Token*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/restricted-tokens)

> When a restricted process or thread tries to access a securable
>   object, the system performs **two** access checks: one using the
>   token's enabled SIDs, and another using the **list of restricting SIDs**.
>   Access is granted only if **both** access checks allow the requested
>   access rights.

in list of restricted SIDs we will be have 4 Sids:

- [service SID](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/voy/2007/03/22/per-service-sid/)
- World SID *S-1-1-0*
- Service logon SID
- Write-restricted SID *S-1-5-33*

so now your service will be have read access to share only if you enable this access for Everyone (S-1-1-0) or concrete your Service Sid or to Write-restricted SID *S-1-5-33* (*NT AUTHORITY\WRITE RESTRICTED*)

dont know how add *NT AUTHORITY\WRITE RESTRICTED* via standard permissions dialog from UI, but this of course possible do via win api. example on c++

```
#include <lm.h>

ULONG SetWriteRestricted(PCWSTR ShareName)
{
    PSHARE_INFO_502 psi = 0;

    ULONG dwError = NetShareGetInfo(0, const_cast<PWSTR>(ShareName), 502, (PBYTE*)&psi);

    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR security_descriptor;

    if (!dwError)
    {
        dwError = ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;

        if (psi && (security_descriptor = psi->shi502_security_descriptor))
        {
            ULONG cb = GetSidLengthRequired(1);
            PVOID Sid = alloca(cb);

            //CreateWellKnownSid(::WinWriteRestrictedCodeSid, 0, Sid, &cb);
            static SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
            InitializeSid(Sid, &NtAuthority, 1);
            *GetSidSubAuthority(Sid, 0) = SECURITY_WRITE_RESTRICTED_CODE_RID;

            bool bExist = false;

            ::PACL Dacl;
            BOOL bPresent, bDefault;

            if (GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(security_descriptor, &bPresent, &Dacl, &bDefault) && bPresent)
            {
                if (ULONG AceCount = Dacl ? Dacl->AceCount : 0)
                {
                    union {
                        PBYTE pb;
                        PVOID pv;
                        PACE_HEADER pah;
                        PACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE paaa;
                    };
                    pv = Dacl + 1;
                    do 
                    {
                        switch (pah->AceType)
                        {
                        case ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE:
                        case ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE:
                            if (EqualSid(&paaa->SidStart, Sid))
                            {
                                bExist = true, AceCount = 1;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (pb += pah->AceSize, --AceCount);
                }

                if (bExist)
                {
                    dwError = NOERROR;
                }
                else
                {
                    USHORT AclSize = Dacl ? Dacl->AclSize : sizeof(ACL), 
                        NewAclSize = AclSize + FIELD_OFFSET(ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE, SidStart) + (USHORT)cb;

                    ::PACL NewDacl = (::PACL)alloca(NewAclSize);

                    if (Dacl) 
                    {
                        memcpy(NewDacl, Dacl, AclSize);
                        NewDacl->AclSize = NewAclSize;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        InitializeAcl(NewDacl, NewAclSize, ACL_REVISION);
                    }

                    if (AddAccessAllowedAce(NewDacl, ACL_REVISION, FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE, Sid))
                    {
                        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
                        InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);

                        if (SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, NewDacl, FALSE))
                        {
                            SHARE_INFO_1501 si = { 0, &sd };

                            dwError = NetShareSetInfo(0, const_cast<PWSTR>(ShareName), 1501, (PBYTE)&si, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NetApiBufferFree(psi);

    return dwError;
}
```

code check are *S-1-5-33* already exist on share and in this case do nothing (not look for actual access - later this already possible edit via UI). if *S-1-5-33* yet not exist - i add read+execute permissions for write restricted sid

i for test apply this for "inetpub" share (`SetWriteRestricted(L"inetpub" );`)

[image]